# FileInputStream пропускает несколько байтов

Tags: java, файлы, io

У меня есть файл:

```html
55 6d 61 78 64 61 73 69 6c 76 61 71 00 09 63 73 61 63 61 73 73 73 63
U  m  a  x  d  a  s  i  l  v  a  q     \t c  s  a  c  a  s  s  s  c
```

Выполняю код на Java:

```html
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("...");
int b;
while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b) + ' ');
fis.close();
```

И получаю вывод:

```html
55 3f 09 63 73 61 63 61 73 73 73 63
U  ?  \t c  s  a  c  a  s  s  s  c
```

В котором наблюдается, что пропущено несколько байтов (а если быть точнее, то 12!), а также возникает несуществующий байт 0x3F

У кого была подобная проблема, подскажите, как исправить. До этого все работало исправно

Comment: Если до этого работало исправно, то что вы изменили? Этот же файл читали и этим же кодом?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/649691)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Поток работает некорректно при использовании относительного пути объекта:

```
File ("./file.txt")
```

Все стало работать исправно при применении абсолютного пути до файла.